# Error Importing existing customers to Shopify using csv file

Tags: csv, shopify

I'm trying to change my customer's address by using bulk CSV import/export way.

I tried on one of my existing customers. However, the result shows a failed import. May I know what may be the problem as I think the steps are quite straightforward. I've attached the steps as below.

1. export csv files
   [image]
2. edit in excel. here I change the address only a bit.
   [image]
3. upload the files by the import
   [image]
4. error message.
   [image]

This customer is active in my shop. is it that I cannot edit an active customer or any condition that must be fulfilled in order to update? Thanks for any response.

Comment: No, you can change customer address at any time, it is not dependent on active orders. Did you get any reason why customer import failed? After finishing the import Shopify return response of how many rows affected or failed.

Comment: did you get solution?

Comment: yes, actually if user has duplicate email/phone number with any other account it will fail to be imported. thanks.

Comment: Happy to help you thanks